# How are mathematical expressions of this kind read in German (with fraction and root)?

Tags: pronunciation, suffix, mathematics

[image: First fraction]         [image: Second fraction]

My guesses are:

1. ein fünfte Wurzel aus a plus c Quadrat-tel / ein Kubikwurzel aus p-tel
2. eins durch fünfte Wurzel aus a plus c Quadrat / eins durch Kubikwurzel aus p

---

These are just examples, I want to understand how are complicated fractions read commonly, always with suffix '-tel' or normally you can use 'durch'.

Comment: Auch wenn es nicht die Frage ist, "... aus Klammer auf a plus c Klammer zu Quadrat ..." - ohne Klammern bedeutet es etwas anderes. Überhaupt können zur Vermeidung von Missverständnissen weitere Klammern in der gesprochenen Sprache nötig sein.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One possibility would be:

> Eins durch (die) fünfte Wurzel aus a plus c (zum) Quadrat.

And

> Eins durch (die) dritte Wurzel aus p.

So in general, you would use:

> Zähler durch Nenner

for fractions and

> x-te Wurzel aus

for the root part.

So your second guess was quite right.

*-tel* is normally just used for very simple fractions like ⅓ (*ein Drittel*) or 1/x (*ein X-tel*).

Comment: Nach plus c kommt eine kurze Sprechpause, damit sich das Quadrieren auf die Summe und nicht nur auf c bezieht.

Comment: Oder man liest es vor: Klammer auf, `a` plus `c`, Klammer zu, zum Quadrat.

Comment: Side notes: 1. Auch "a plus c in Klammern zum Quadrat" möglich. 2. Ganz allgemein im Fall von 1/x kann man noch von Kehrwert reden (was natürlich nicht auf 1/x reduziert ist, da 3/5 auch der Kehrwert von 5/3 ist, aber spricht es sich hier einfach leichter...), z.b. "Der Kehrwert der 5ten Wurzel von a und c in Klammern zum Quadrat". 3. "Wurzel aus" und "Wurzel von" sind beide (gefühlsmäßig, basierend auf besuchte Vorlesungen) gleichermaßen häufig verwendet.

Comment: "Eins durch dritte Wurzel p" wäre auch möglich, und geläufiger als "Kubikwurzel". "Dritte Wurzel p invers" auch, aber eher ungewöhnlich. Wo das Quadrat steht ist in Prosa schwer zu vermitteln, wenn man nicht weitere Klammern spricht, die nicht geschrieben werden müssen. "Eins durch fünfte Wurzel aus Klammer auf a plus c Klammer zu Quadrat" kann auch als 1/(5th √(a+c))² oder (1/ 5th √(a+c))² verstanden werden.

Comment: Ich kenne das so: "a plus c Quadrat" → a+c², "a plus c im Quadrat" → (a+c)². Auch "das Quadrat von a plus c" ist (a+c)² – das wäre dann auch meine Wahl im obigen Ausdruck: "Eins durch die fünfte Wurzel aus dem Quadrat von a plus c".

Comment: @celtschk: Wieso ist "a plus c im Quadrat" nicht auch als "a + c²" interpretierbar - "c im Quadrat" ist doch "c²"? Ebenso "das Quadrat von a plus c" kann "a²+c" sein. Da Quadrat stärker bindet als plus würde ich sogar sagen, dass die zweite Interpretation zwingend ist.

Comment: @userunknown: Weil das eben die Konvention ist, die ich kenne.

Comment: @celtschk: Unter wo/bei wem gilt diese Konvention? In Ostwestfalen, unter Investmentbankern, ...?

Comment: @userunknown: Eine genaue Angabe kann ich da nicht machen, weil mich diese Frage nie interessiert hat (falls es eine regionale Konvention ist, dann käme aber wohl nur Oberbayern in Betracht). Ich habe die Konvention einfach aus Schulzeiten übernommen, ohne mir darüber groß Gedanken zu machen (ich weiß nicht einmal, ob die Konvention jemals explizit gelehrt wurde oder ich sie nur implizit übernommen habe). Jedenfalls hatte ich mit dieser Konvention noch nie Verständigungsschwierigkeiten, und das ist letztlich das einzige, was für mich zählt.

Comment: @celtschk: Da man selten Formeln mündlich übermittelt wäre also denkbar, dass es gar keine Konvention gibt, sondern Deine Interpretationen nur zufällig dem Deiner seltenen Gesprächspartner in solchen Angelegenheiten entsprochen hat?

Comment: @userunknown: Nachdem ich sie explizit benutze, gibt es die Konvention, sonst könnte ich sie ja nicht benutzen. Was ich aber in der Tat nicht ausschließen kann, ist, dass die Zahl derjenigen Personen, die diese Konvention benutzen, sehr klein ist (aber sicher mindestens 1 :-)). Jedenfalls finde ich diese Konvention äußerst praktisch, weil man auf diese Weise sich viele unnötige Worte erspart. Wobei ich mich im übrigen frage, warum hier bernd_k's äußerst subtile Sprechpause nicht so intensiver Nachforschung unterzogen wird wie die von mir erwähnte Regel.

Comment: @celtschk: Diese Sprechpause wäre jedenfalls auch das, was ich als meine Konvention behaupten würde. "$a$ plus $b$ (pause pause) mal (pause) $a$ minus $b$ (pause) ist $a$ Quadrat minus $b$ Quadrat" für $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ (im Zweifelsfall plus und minus der linken Seite noch besonders betont), aber "$a$ plus $b$mal$a$ minus $b$" wäre $a+ba-b$.

Answer (score 7):

> Kehrwert der fünften Wurzel des Quadrats der Summe aus a und c.

Die Klammer wird hier meiner Erfahrung nach nicht gesprochen, da sie aus der Benennung als 'Summe' bereits hervorgeht.

> Kehrwert der Kubikwurzel aus p.

Alternativ zu *Kubikwurzel* auch *dritte Wurzel*.

Answer (score 1):

Für den ersten Bruch kann man in Deutsch auch sagen:

1. Eins gebrochen die fünfte Wurzel von *a* plus *c* in Klammern zum Quadrat
2. Der Kehrwert der fünften Wurzel von *a* plus *c* in Klammern zum Quadrat

Dabei bedeutet "Kehrwert" das Gleiche wie "eins durch". "Gebrochen" entspricht "durch", wobei "gebrochen" beim Diktieren klar macht, dass nun ein Bruchstrich geschrieben werden soll. "In Klammern" bedeutet, dass der vorstehende (oder auch nachfolgende) Term in Klammern zu setzen ist (manchmal nicht einfach zu erkennen, wo die Schlussklammer hinkommt). "Zum Quadrat" entspricht "hoch zwei" (impliziert hier auch, dass zuvor die schließende Klammer zu schreiben ist).

Ist die Klammer unter der Wurzel etwas komplizierter, dann ist unter Umständen "in Klammern" nicht mehr eindeutig. Dann sagt man besser:

- Der Kehrwert der fünften Wurzel von Klammer auf *a* plus *c* Klammer zu hoch zwei
- Eins durch die fünfte Wurzel von Klammer auf *a* plus *c* Klammer zu hoch zwei

Analog sagt man für den zweiten Bruch:

1. Eins gebrochen dritte Wurzel *p*
2. Eins gebrochen dritte Wurzel aus/von *p*
3. Eins gebrochen Kubikwurzel *p*
4. Kehrwert dritte Wurzel *p*
5. Kehrwert der Kubikwurzel *p*

Bei einfachen Termen kann man "von" oder "aus" auch weglassen, falls der mathematische Ausdruck dadurch nicht verfälscht wird. Normalerweise hat in der Mathematik eine geschriebene Klammer auf und Klammer zu eine wichtige Bedeutung (z. B. keine Anwendung der Regel Punkt vor Strich) und sollte deshalb immer auch gesprochen werden. So bleibt der mathematische Ausdruck eindeutig.

Quadrat- und Kubikwurzel sind Spezialfälle, die die zweite und dritte Wurzel bezeichnen. Allgemeingültig ist immer: "*x*-te Wurzel von …", wobei *x* für eine ganze Zahl steht.

Die Wortendung -tel ist eine andere Ausdrucksweise für einen einfachen Kehrwert, der nur aus einer ganzen Zahl *x* im Nenner besteht: 1/*x*. Also 1/1 wird auch "ein Eintel" gesprochen, 1/8 "ein Achtel", 1/10 "ein Zehntel". "Ein Achtele" oder "ein Viertele" bedeutet in der Weinstube, dass der Gast 1/8 Liter Wein oder 1/4 Liter Wein trinken möchte.

Comment: „Eins gebrochen die“? Kenn’ ich gar nicht! Sehr, sehr selten „Eins gebrochen durch die" oder viel häufiger bis fast ausschließlich „Eins durch die“! Oder eben dann „Kehrwert aus der“ (mit ‚aus‘!), wobei ich nur „das Reziproke“ kennengelernt habe.

Comment: In Bayern (zumindest als ich zur Schule ging) wurde "gebrochen" mit oder ohne "die" gerne dann verwendet, um klarzustellen, dass nun ein Bruchstrich kommt. Das war dem Schüler sehr hilfreich beim Schreiben der Aufgabe, wenn der Lehrer sie diktiert hat. Woher kommst Du, wenn Du dies nicht kennst?

Comment: Berliner Raum, DDR-sozialisiert, was gerade bei solchen Dingen ein Unterschied selbst zu West-Berlin sein kann.

Comment: Ich bin in Baden-Württemberg zur Schule gegangen. Das „gebrochen“ ist mir so fremd wie Speravir.